# Cohn Measure Theory exercise question 9 chapter 1.3

Tags: measure-theory

This exercise can be found in Cohn's book about measure theory (exercise 9, chapter 1.3, p. 22):

> Define $\mu^*(A) := \lambda^*(\pi(A))$ for $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$,
>   $\pi(x,y) := x$ and $\lambda^*$ Lebesgue outer measure on
>   $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mu^*$ is an outer measure. Show, that $B
>  \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable with respect to $\mu^*$ if and
>   only if there exists $B_0, B_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue
>   measurable, $B_0 \subseteq B_1$, $\lambda^*(B_1\setminus B_0) = 0$ and
>   $B_0 \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq B \subseteq B_1 \times \mathbb{R}$.

Somehow I am stuck proving the direction $\Leftarrow$. My attempt: Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Then

\begin{align}
\mu^*(A \cap B) + \mu^*(A \cap B^c) &\leq \mu^*(A \cap (B_1 \times \mathbb{R})) + \mu^*(A \cap (B_0 \times \mathbb{R})^c)\\
&= \lambda^*(\pi(A \cap (B_1 \times \mathbb{R}))) + \lambda^*(\pi(A \cap (B_0 \times \mathbb{R})^c))\\
&\leq \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap \pi(B_1 \times \mathbb{R}))) + \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap \pi((B_0 \times \mathbb{R})^c)))\\
&= \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_1) + \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_0^c)
\end{align}

Maybe this is completely wrong. Has someone another idea or an idea how to proceed?

Comment: The last step is correct. $B_0$ being lebesgue measurable means precisely that $\lambda^*(E \cap B_0) + \lambda^*( E \cap (B_0)^c) = \lambda^*(E)$ for _any_ set $E$, so in particular for any set of the form $\pi(A)$. This does not say anything on the measurability of $\pi(A) \cap B_0$ or of $\pi(A)$.

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. Oh sure, what an oversight. Thanks. Accepted and +1.

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. Just to be entirely sure: We could drop the requirement that $B_1$ is Lebesgue measurable, right?

Comment: Yes. In any case, we suppose that $B_1$ and $B_0$ differ by a null set, so the measurability of any one of the two implies measurability of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there!

**Hint:** From your last inequality, write $B_1 = B_0 \cup ( B_1 \setminus B_0)$ and use subadditivity.

Also, your third line should be an inequality. We always have the inclusion $\pi(A \cap (B_1 \times \mathbb{R})) \subset \pi(A) \cap \pi( B_1 \times \mathbb{R})$, but not equality in general. So you need to use monotonicity here.

Comment: Thanks for your nice hint. I've edited my post and I am lacking a bit of verification of my last step. Maybe you have an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint we get

\begin{align}
\mu^*(A \cap B) + \mu^*(A \cap B^c) &\leq \mu^*(A \cap (B_1 \times \mathbb{R})) + \mu^*(A \cap (B_0 \times \mathbb{R})^c)\\
&= \lambda^*(\pi(A \cap (B_1 \times \mathbb{R}))) + \lambda^*(\pi(A \cap (B_0 \times \mathbb{R})^c))\\
&\leq \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap \pi(B_1 \times \mathbb{R}))) + \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap \pi((B_0 \times \mathbb{R})^c)))\\
&= \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_1) + \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_0^c)\\ &= \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap (B_0 \cup (B_1\setminus B_0))) + \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_0^c)\\
&= \lambda^*((\pi(A) \cap B_0) \cup (\pi(A) \cap (B_1\setminus B_0))) + \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_0^c)\\
&\leq \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_0) + \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap (B_1\setminus B_0)) + \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_0^c)\\
&= \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_0) + \lambda^*(\pi(A) \cap B_0^c) \\
&= \lambda^*(\pi(A))\end{align}

For any $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.