# Cohn Measure Theory exercise question 9 chapter 1.3 other direction

Tags: measure-theory

This exercise can be found in Cohn's book about measure theory (exercise 9, chapter 1.3, p. 22) and I have already asked for help for the direction $\Leftarrow$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995075/cohn-measure-theory-exercise-question-9-chapter-1-3):

> Define $\mu^*(A) := \lambda^*(\pi(A))$ for $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$,
>   $\pi(x,y) := x$ and $\lambda^*$ Lebesgue outer measure on
>   $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mu^*$ is an outer measure. Show, that $B
>  \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable with respect to $\mu^*$ if and
>   only if there exists $B_0, B_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue
>   measurable, $B_0 \subseteq B_1$, $\lambda^*(B_1\setminus B_0) = 0$ and
>   $B_0 \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq B \subseteq B_1 \times \mathbb{R}$.

However, I do not quite get the direction $\Rightarrow$. My idea was to define some sets $B_0$ and $B_1$ and then to show that they fulfill the given properties. I think a good choice of $B_1$ would be $\pi(B)$ since then $B \subseteq B_1 \times \mathbb{R}$. I am not sure how to prove that the so defined $B_1$ is Lebesgue measurable and I am not sure how to define $B_0$ aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of $B_1$ is right. To see it is Lebesgue measurable, take any set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and notice that $A= \pi(A \times \mathbb{R})$. Then:
\begin{align}
\lambda^*(A \cap B_1) + \lambda^*(A \cap (B_1)^c)  
&= \lambda^*( \pi(A \times \mathbb{R}) \cap \pi(B) ) + \lambda^*(\pi(A\times \mathbb{R}) \cap \pi(B)^c) \\
&\leq \lambda^*( \pi( (A\times \mathbb{R}) \cap B))+ \lambda^*(\pi((A\times \mathbb{R}) \cap B^c))
\end{align}

(I'll let you fill in the details of why this last step is correct.)

The choice of $B_0$ is the tricky part, but once we get the idea it is not so hard. Define $B_0 = \pi(B) \cap \pi(B^c)^c$. Here's a drawing to see why this is a good choice (but beware, the set $B$ in the drawing will not be measurable):

[image]

I am not so good at drawing on the computer but I hope this gives an idea. Now, clearly $B_0 \subset B_1$, and $B_0 \times \mathbb{R} \subset B$. What remains is to see that $\lambda^*(B_1 \setminus B_0) =0$.

**Hint:** To do this, remember that $B$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, so for any set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ we have:
$$
\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A \cap B) + \mu^*(A \cap B^c)
$$
Now, if the result *were* to be true, $B$ should be very close (in measure) to the rectangle $\pi(B) \times \mathbb{R}$. This gives us a clue that we should try to put $A= \pi(B) \times \mathbb{R}$ in this equality and see where this gets us.

Comment: Oh it is you again! I hoped you would answer. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure, this is a nice problem. I tried to give hints rather than a full solution, so my answer will probably be hard to follow at first... Don't hesitate if you have questions. And try to draw some easy sets and decide if they are measurable or not, that's how I understood this problem.

Comment: Nice and not so easy I think. Hints are always better, one has to fully understand the problem. So a question arised: Why exactly is $B_0 \times \mathbb{R} \subseteq B$? I mean from the drwaing it is clear but I do not see how to prove it.

Comment: You can see it by contradiction: suppose you had a point $(x,t) \in B_0 \times \mathbb{R}$ with $(x,t) \in B^c$. Then $x = \pi(x,t) \in \pi(B^c)$, which contradicts the fact that $x \in B_0$.

Comment: It seems that we can take $B_0=\pi(B^c)^c$ since $\pi(B^c)^c\subseteq\pi(B)$.